# Reroute to a profile page w/user data Angular2 and Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set up a profile page route after the user has signed in through Firebase. My `signin` component includes a path to the `profile` route. The only problem here is that my profile component has user data that comes from a Firebase DB. And as a result, when I am redirected to my profile page, I get an error of `Cannot read property 'uid' of null`.

If I refresh the page after signing in, then my profile page comes up with no errors.

My **signin.component.ts**

```
  signInSubmit(){
    var self = this;
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(self.signInForm.value.smail, self.signInForm.value.spassword).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error.message);
    });
    localStorage.setItem('confirmo', 'verdad');
    self.router.navigate(['profile']);
  }
```

My **profile.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
   var self = this;
   let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;  
   let userNamePath = `users/${user.uid}/username`;
   let notesPath = `users/${user.uid}/addnote`;

this.username$ = this.af.database.object(userNamePath);
this.addsnotes$ = this.af.database.list(notesPath);

function redis(){ 
   self.proshow = true; }
   setTimeout(redis, 3000);
}
```

To attempt to solve this, I placed a timeout before showing my profile component. However, this does not work. Even if I put my entire `ngOnInit` inside a timeout function, the same error shows up.

Also, a portion of my **profile.component.html** if it helps.

```
<h4>Welcome {{ (username$ | async)?.$value }}</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be the almighty onAuthStateChanged. Like so:

**profile.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
var self = this;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
if (user){ 
var userNamePath = `users/${user.uid}/username`;
var notesPath = `users/${user.uid}/addnote`;

self.username$ = self.af.database.object(userNamePath);
self.addsnotes$ = self.af.database.list(notesPath);
self.proshow = true;
}
});
```

}